# Is there any difference in the words "roast" and "fry" in German?

Tags: verb, difference

Is there any difference in the words "roast" and "fry" in German?  Or are they both just *braten*?
Here are some definitions for them: [fry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Fry), [roast](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/roast)

Comment: See http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frittieren, http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braten_(Garmethode), http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rösten_(Zubereitungsart) and also the list in http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garen

Comment: So do you think "roast" = "Rösten" and "fry" = "Braten" would be a good translation?

Comment: Read also the answers here: http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1509180&langid=3

Answer (score 5):

This is one of the cases, where the distinctions are somewhat different (and pretty much arbitrary) in English and German. Also, it will depend on whether you're talking to a chef or someone who's never been in a kitchen, or someone in between.

There is a lot of overlap, though, so that in most cases *braten* will cover what you want to say.

Some examples where Germans use a different term than *braten*:

- roasting something in a dry pan or griddle (onions, oil seeds, coffee): *rösten*. The focus here is on high temperature, no fat or oil, usually for releasing and creating flavours by caramelization and the Maillard reaction. This is afaik the only instance where these two can be used interchangeably; the definition of *rösten* is much narrower than *to roast*.
- roasting something in a pan with a little fat or oil, with initially high temperature: *anbraten*, *bräunen*.
- frying something in a pan with rather more fat or oil, to the point of deep frying: *backen* or *ausbacken*. "Backfisch", for example, is a fish fillet in batter, fried or deep fried.

I'll try to add more examples :)

Comment: "Grillen/grillieren" fehlt noch ;)

Comment: I have given +1 for the informative answer, and if I could I would give another +1 for *Backfisch*.

Comment: Contrary to what you wrote, _anschwitzen_ uses (relatively) **low** heat; even though no water is added, the own liquid from the vegetables (not limited to onions) is enough to keep the temperature near 100 °C, and browning does not occur. The English term is apparently _sweating_.

Answer (score 4):

I know nothing of this, but what I intended to be a comment has become long enough for an answer.

The words “rösten”, “braten” and “frittieren” all describe ways to prepare food that are relevant here. You can find their exact meaning by looking at the corresponding articles in the German language Wikipedia. There may be more words of interest to be found in the article “[Garen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garen)”.

“Rösten” ist “roast”, but as in coffee beans. The pictures for “[Braten](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braten_%28Garmethode%29)” look very much like those for “[roasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roasting)”, which should sufficiently explain this word. (The German page also links to the English page. This is a good way to use Wikipedia to find translations for things like these, very useful with animals and plants. Unfortunately the English page links to the page for “rösten”, which seems to be a bad choice.)

Finally, “[frittieren](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frittieren)” is definitely how you prepare French fries. That seems to be “deep-frying” in English.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my gosh there has to be some way of saying "fried eggs". In Yiddish we have *praegeln*, as in the following quatrain from the Ballad of Monisch by I. L. Peretz, in which the Devil and Lilith are having a quiet morning at home:

Sée shmuessen (chat) vertraut, vun dem un vun jenem;

Wemen zu packen ‘erein in Gehenum.

Wemen zu schmeissen mit eiserne rüter,

Un wemen zu präglen zu’m frühstuck mit putter.

Comment: Again, Wikipedia links [fried egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fried_egg) to [Spiegelei](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spiegelei), with similar words in Danish, Norwegian and Icelandic, but not in Swedish.

Comment: Lol, these are definitely *gebraten* - and are called *Spiegeleier*, *Ochsenaugen*, *Setzeier*... (Strictly speaking, *Spiegeleier* are fried eggs that have been heated in the oven after frying, so that the clear film on the yolk turns white (a bit like *over easy*), but outside professional kitchens it's the commonest term.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt of a quick (probably inexact) overview:

## fry - frittieren / braten / backen.

**Frittieren**

- These one see to be close, but rather by orthography
- is only used when something floats in fat/oil (notwithstanding regional differences).
- still pastry (Fettgebäck, Siedegeback) one uses [`in heißem Fett schwimmend ausgebacken`](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siedegeb%C3%A4ck)

**Braten**

- without or just few oil (not floating)

## roast - rösten / braten

**Rösten**

- without fat and water

**Braten**

- in the oven (not pastry)